# Is it possible in C++ to initialize a const Int with scanf() or std::cin << or some input function like that?

Tags: c++, arrays, types, constants

I want to declare an `array[x]`, but I want my array's size changeable for every each new programm start. My first idea was `int x; scanf("%d",&x);` one line before I declare my `array[x]` but that doesent work because x have to be a const int.

My next idea was simply make a `const int x; scanf("%d", &x);` but this try also failed, because
`array[x]` or rather say the const int x must be initialized before I can start the programm.

My last idea was to initialized the x `const int x = 1;` and on the next time `scanf("%d", &x);`
In this try the programm didnt crashed, but it wasnt usefull. In the moment if I start the programm my `array[x]` got initialized with my "old" x. So my changed x have no impact.

Do u have any ideas how I can solve this little problem or this there no way to initialize a const int or overall a const type after I start the programm in C++?

Comment: Read in the `x`.  Output source code using that `x` value that does what you want.  Compile that generated code.  Run the program from the generated code.  Alternatively, use `std::vector`.

Comment: It seems like what you want is a constant expression, which is not something you can get at run time. If the purpose is to use it as an array dimension, you could just use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't do this directly.
What you can do is to use this idea:

```
const int x = []{int x; scanf("%d", &x); return x;}();
```

For an array,

```
const std::vector<double> v = []{
 int x; scanf("%d", &x);
 std::vector<double> v(x);
 ...fill v...
 return v;
}();
```

If you want an array that is fixed in size (after initialization) but with modifiable elements, you have to look even beyond to a static_vector kind of structure.
(This variation of array is not a nice type to work with anyway).

Comment: Thx, I will try it